# Ng-Click remember radio button selection

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

I'm trying to create a form on multiple views. 
How would I make it so if a user goes back, their choice is still stored?

View 1

```
   <div>
                <em style="font-size: 2.75em">{{message}}</em>
            </div>
            <br /><br />
            <p>What Color do you like?</p>
            <br /><br />
            <div class="col-xs-offset-4">
                <form role="form" >
                    <div class="radio">
                        <label><input type="radio" name="optradio" value="yellow" id="yellow">Yellow</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="radio">
                        <label><input type="radio" name="optradio" value="blue" id="blue">Blue</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="radio">
                        <label><input type="radio" name="optradio" value="green" id="green">Green</label>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>

            <br /><br />

            <div ng-controller="MyController" >
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="myData.doClick()">Next </button>
            </div>
```

Script.js

```
scotchApp.controller("MyController", function($scope) {
    $scope.myData = {};
    $scope.myData.doClick = function() {
      parent.location='#q_two';
    }
} );
```

any help | a good place to look to read more | or a way to think about this 
would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could maintain a service to stored the changes, and `getter` & `setter`

**Service**

```
app.service('data', function() {
    this.data = {
        radioValue: false;
    };
    this.getRadioValueData = function() {
        return this.data.radioValue;
    };
    this.setRadioValueData = function(val) {
        this.data.radioValue = val;
    };
});
```

**Code**

```
scotchApp.controller("MyController", function($scope, data) {
    $scope.data = data;
    $scope.myData.doClick = function() {
        $scope.data.setRadioValueData();
    };
});
```

In other controller you could get the value of change radio button by `$scope.data.getRadioValueData();`